# MySQL select query does not return any entry

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have imported the current Stack Overflow data dump into a MySQL database. But I am not able to query any data. For example `SELECT Body FROM Posts;` is returning 0 rows.

How can this be if the database is obviously not empty? How can I access the data? Any help is appreciated!

---

This is the import script I have used:

```
create database stackoverflow_com DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

use stackoverflow_com;

CREATE TABLE Posts (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PostTypeId TINYINT NOT NULL ,
    AcceptedAnswerId INT,
    ParentId INT,
    CreationDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    DeletionDate DATETIME,
    Score INT NULL,
    ViewCount INT NULL,
    Body text NULL,
    OwnerUserId INT,
    OwnerDisplayName varchar(256),
    LastEditorUserId INT,
    LastEditorDisplayName VARCHAR(40),
    LastEditDate DATETIME,
    LastActivityDate DATETIME,
    Title varchar(256),
    Tags VARCHAR(256),
    AnswerCount INT DEFAULT 0,
    CommentCount INT DEFAULT 0,
    FavoriteCount INT DEFAULT 0,
    ClosedDate DATETIME,
    CommunityOwnedDate DATETIME
);

load xml infile 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\Posts.xml'
into table Posts
rows identified by '<row>';

create index Posts_idx_1 on Posts(AcceptedAnswerId);
create index Posts_idx_2 on Posts(ParentId);
create index Posts_idx_3 on Posts(OwnerUserId);
create index Posts_idx_4 on Posts(LastEditorUserId);
```

Example of a row in the xml import file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<posts>
  <row Id="4" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="7" CreationDate="2008-07-31T21:42:52.667" Score="441" ViewCount="29333" Body="&lt;p&gt;I want to use a track-bar to change a form's opacity.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;This is my code:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000;&#xA;this.Opacity = trans;&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;When I try to build it, I get this error:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;blockquote&gt;&#xA;  &lt;p&gt;Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'double'.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;/blockquote&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I tried making &lt;code&gt;trans&lt;/code&gt; a &lt;code&gt;double&lt;/code&gt;, but then the control doesn't work. This code has worked fine for me in VB.NET in the past. &lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="8" LastEditorUserId="5455605" LastEditorDisplayName="Rich B" LastEditDate="2015-12-23T21:34:28.557" LastActivityDate="2016-07-17T20:33:18.217" Title="When setting a form's opacity should I use a decimal or double?" Tags="&lt;c#&gt;&lt;winforms&gt;&lt;type-conversion&gt;&lt;decimal&gt;&lt;opacity&gt;" AnswerCount="13" CommentCount="3" FavoriteCount="36" CommunityOwnedDate="2012-10-31T16:42:47.213" />
</posts>
```

Some statistics about the created database:

[image]

Comment: Does `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Posts` return the correct result?

Comment: No, it returns `0`. Was it maybe a flawed import?

Comment: Can you post a single row element enclosed in the xml file?

Comment: I have added an example row in my post.

Comment: Thanks. I have reproduced the steps you pointed out in your question and successfully imported the row you posted. Do you have multiple tables `posts`? The one you are showing statistics of is called `posts`, but you are querying a table called `Posts` (Might not be a difference on windows though)

Comment: Thanks for your try. I only have the `posts` table. Uppercase or lowercase does not make any difference (I am running Windows).

Comment: Yeah, shouldn't make a difference there. Did you try to import a subset of the list only (or the one row only) ---- or did you try to limit the resultset? Just trying to narrowing down the problem... :)

Comment: Yes, I also tried to import the one single line above, but it suddenly gives my this error: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<posts>
  <row Id="4" PostTypeId="1" Acce' at line 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this should not happen, but you can try some troubleshooting by following commands

1. Check that your table returning anything or not `select * from Posts`
2. Check your body doesnt have a character set that does'nt fit in `UTF8` as you defined your table to be limited to `UTF8`.
3. Create a another test table with only 1 row from that XML file , and test your commands

If any error throwed then please post that error

Comment: 1. It only returns `Empty set (0.00 sec)`. 2. How do I check this in such a huge file? At least the XML file is declared as UTF-8. 3. I have tried to import another test table with just the row I have added to my original post. But it suddenly gives me this error: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<posts>
  <row Id="4" PostTypeId="1" Acce' at line 1`

Comment: this means your insert query is not correct for storing row in table, it have some syntax problem as already shown in the error itself, i noticed that you have mutiple semicolons in your data , i think that might be the problem , so search how to store strings in mysql that have characters like semicolon, commas etc , just give it a try